# Stack Exchange site for Arabic language questions?

Tags: support, languages, translations

I am searching for a Stack Exchange site where I can put my question related to the Arabic language.

I tried putting my question on Linguistics Stack Exchange, and it got comments that my question was off-topic: [Difference between طريق and الصراط](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/30968/difference-between-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%82-and-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B7)

I posted my question on Islam Stack Exchange and had the same issue there as on Linguistics: [Difference between طريق and الصراط](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/53374/difference-between-%D8%B7%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%82-and-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B7)